# Selenium - cannot click on hidden element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am working with Selenium and Python. I am struggling to use the `click()` method in order to click a dynamically created radio button. The markup for the radio is below.

```
<input version="2" value="1" class="linked-ftb-radio meta(controlNumber=2)" id="radio_1" name="IndexString" reference="TEST 01" type="radio">
<label for="radio_1" id="linked-label" class="radio-label"></label>
```

The code I have is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="radio_1"]').click()
```

However the following error is produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 41, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="radio_1"]').click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 74, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 457, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

The radio appears to be simulated by changing the image when the label is pressed. In other words, when clicked the class changes to `radio-label selected`.

[image: radio]

How can I click on the radio button with Selenium, bearing in mind it is not currently visible?

Comment: What happens if you add a pause before the click? (This is not the solution, only a further debug step)

Comment: I think clicking on label would select the checkbox, you should once as `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('label[for="radio_1"]').click()` and let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `explicit condition` to wait for the element to be displayed. (if it is time-related issue, i.e., takes time to display)

```
 element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='radio_1']"))
 element.click()
```

> This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException or if it is present on the DOM of a page and visible, will return it in 0 - 10 seconds. WebDriverWait by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully. A successful return is for ExpectedCondition type is Boolean return true or not null return value for all other ExpectedCondition types.

Reference:

1. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located
2. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 1):

**C#**

You can use waiter to element to become visible like this:

```
var element = Waiter.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("ID"))).FirstOrDefault();
```